# kafka-topics.sh : bootstrap-server is not a recognized option

Tags: apache-kafka

my kafka version "kafka_2.11-2.1.0"

`./kafka-topics.sh --describe --bootstrap-server master:9092 --topic test`

```
Exception in thread "main" joptsimple.UnrecognizedOptionException: bootstrap-server is not a recognized option
        at joptsimple.OptionException.unrecognizedOption(OptionException.java:108)
        at joptsimple.OptionParser.handleLongOptionToken(OptionParser.java:510)
        at joptsimple.OptionParserState$2.handleArgument(OptionParserState.java:56)
        at joptsimple.OptionParser.parse(OptionParser.java:396)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$TopicCommandOptions.<init>(TopicCommand.scala:361)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:44)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using Kafka 2.1.0? What happens if you use `--zookeeper` option?

Comment: I tried it -- ZooKeeper is now running the command, thank you very much

Comment: Keep in mind that option is now deprecated, so I'd strongly recommend that you upgrade Kafka to a version that does support bootstrap servers

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. We will upgrade Kafka later

Answer (score 0):

Run the command by itself to look at supported options.

If it doesn't exist, then you are likely not using the version of the CLI that supports that option.

Example with grepping for `bootstrap`...

```
$ /usr/local/Cellar/kafka/3.2.3/libexec/bin/kafka-topics.sh 2>&1 | grep bootstrap
--bootstrap-server <String: server to    REQUIRED: The Kafka server to connect
                                           only with --bootstrap-server option
                                           create if --bootstrap-server option
                                           a --bootstrap-server option).
                                           the --bootstrap-server option.
                                           only with --bootstrap-server option
```